# Sidenav selected item list displaying improperly 365 online

Tags: css, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

We have a site in sharepoint and 'Document' is the parent folder. '2017' and '2016' is its sub folders. Then we added the two sub folders in the sidenav.

[image]

The problem is, if you select either '2016' or '2017' from the sidenav, the showed selected menu is still 'Documents' which is confusing.

[image]

I have no idea how I will modify this effectively in sharepoint. I tried editting the scripts from master pages but nothing changes. The sidenav of image 1 and 2 is different so I think they have different ID. I don't know how or where to fix this. Please have mercy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought it has something to do with customizing the scripts from masters pages and there you can view/modify/add scripts to brand your website. But I solved it by editing their order and placing the Document(Parent folder) above the sub folders. I don't know if it's a basic knowledge but I don't get how it affects the appearance or the sidenav effects since we use links to the menus. Tried to solve this since yesterday :`(